# I want to turn this flash element on my page into javascript/jquery...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

http://floorsofstone.com/sample-request/

^ The table with stone samples on is the element in question.

How would I even go about describing this so I can find a javascript/jquery alternative to make it easily editable.

If anybody has anything similar please pass on the link...

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could tell you it is possible to do something like that, I don't think you would find an out-of-the-box plugin to handle everything for you.

You would have to have a grid of divs with all your tiles.

- Hook each of the div's (per tile) to a mouseover, mouseout and [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) events.
- On click [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)/remove the element from the main grid
- Show it in the selection.

I would think it would be better to do the whole thing without any animations first.

Then you can add animated effects to make it all look better. Look at JQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [JQueryUI animation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/) for the little mouse over effects.

**Update:** 
Once you are done creating your client behavior (selection..et) and animations. You can then hook the whole thing up to your server with [jquery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

I checked out how that page works. On submit, it loads up a form for some details and posts the data off to this url : *http://floorsofstone.com/sample-request/post-data.aspx*

The popup dialog also contains hidden fields with the selected TileID's, something like this:

```
<input id="TileIDs" type="hidden" value="4005,4004,4003,4002," name="TileIDs">
<input id="Tile1" type="hidden" value="Adobe Quarry Tile" name="Tile1"> 
<input.....
```

So your jquery on submit would be something like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/sample-request/post-data.aspx",
  data:"TileIDs=" + $("#TileIDs").val() + "&ClientName=" + $("#ClientName").val()
  //the "TileIDs"= is the name your server expects and 
  //#TileID is the id of the html field that contains the value 
  }).done(function( msg ) 
     {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
     });
```

Comment: so I have got the basics up and as an alternative I just have opacity to 0.5 on hover.

If I wanted to select a max of 4 images for a submit form to be emailed would I be able to use php or would that be some sort of jquery?

Comment: @sansome you would use javascript with jquery to ensure only four are selected and store that somewhere (Maybe in a javascript array) You then post to your server backend, probably the same way/same format as your flash app does, you could use [jquery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't use javascript or jquery for this.

I would go with CSS3 transitions. When you hover over a div, the tile-image should shrink, with css3 transitions, we can do that in an animated fashion.

HTML

```
<div class="tile">
  <span>sometext</span>
  <img src="tile-1.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tile {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.tile img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.tile:hover img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

NOTE: I haven't tested this, but I think it should be fine.

NOTE 2: this doesn't work in IE 9 and lower. In this example, I personally wouldn't mind that IE doesn't have the nice transition. If you really must, test for css3 transitions with [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), and provide a jquery fallback.

Comment: thanks ThomasM, didn't css3 transitions didn't even cross my mind.